# Specify start time of video when creating ffmpeg mosaic

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a mosaic video by combining recordings of video streams for a WebRTC call application. Each recording is made up of 2 files, it's `.mkv` video and it's `.mka` audio.

The problem I'm facing is that each recording starts at a *different time*. A participant might have started the call and is recording himself while the 2nd participant joins after 1 minute.

For example, Recording 1 starts at `1657135694178` while Recording 2 starts at `1657135711762`, both being Unix timestamps.

This is what I currently do to create the mosaic:

```
$ ffmpeg 
  -i video-1.mkv 
  -i audio-1.mka 
  -i video-2.mkv 
  -i audio-2.mka 
  -filter_complex 
  vstack=inputs=2 
  output-1.mkv
```

Comment: Just add `-ss` option in front of each `-i` option to specify its start time. Not sure if ffmpeg recognizes unix timestamps tho.

Comment: @kesh AFAIK [`-ss` is seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) in a video. I want the 2nd video for example to start after `n` seconds.

Comment: yes. `ffmpeg -ss 1 -i input1 -ss 2 -i input2 ...` starts the streams of the first input at 1 second mark while the streams of the second input start at the 2-second mark. Give it a try and see if it is what you want.

Comment: I'm running this `ffmpeg -ss 2 -i video-1.mkv -i video-2.mkv -filter_complex vstack=inputs=2 out.mkv` but both streams start at the same time.

Comment: oh, are you saying that you want to delay showing the 2nd input in the vstack? If so, do you want to discard input frames prior to that timestamp or start with the first frame of the input?

Comment: start with the first frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`tpad` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad) to insert blank frames like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video-1.mkv -i video-2.mkv -filter_complex \
  "[0:v]tpad=start_duration=1[v1];\
   [1:v]tpad=start_duration=2[v2];\
   [v1][v2]vstack=inputs=2" \
  out.mkv
```

The first frame of the first input starts showing at output time = 1s and 2nd input's first frame to appear at time t=2.

Comment: minor detail but how do I also pad the audio files? As you can see from the OP, my video and audio files are separate.

Comment: Use [`adelay` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay)